# How to fetch a file metadata on server-side

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I am writing a block where I am collecting the [metadata](https://moodle.org/mod/glossary/showentry.php?eid=184&displayformat=dictionary) of a **videofile** and sending it to my block table but problem is 
I want to validate the data on [server](https://moodle.org/mod/glossary/showentry.php?eid=30&displayformat=dictionary) side by checking the **metadata**. for e.g the video has a time duration = 300 seconds,
now I want to validate the **timeduration** variable value that it can't be more then 300 , so how can i get that file information retrieve on server side and validate with my variable.

if value is not exceeding the total timelimit so I can insert into [database](https://moodle.org/mod/glossary/showentry.php?eid=15&displayformat=dictionary).

currently I am retrieving three values which i am able to validate ,
courseid,resrouce id and instance id
these three values are associated with the file information but I am unable to get the way how can i fetch the file metadata.

I tried various website and all details but unable to find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

I know i'm coming a bit late on this question, but i struggled with the same problem today.
I got several solutions but i used FFMPEG that i installed on the server i run moodle, (you'll need php 8 but it should already be the case if you run moodle 4.x)

Then i get the info this way :

```
if (isset($vid) && file_exists($vid)) { //$vid url got with file API
    $ffprobe = FFMpeg\FFProbe::create();
    $vidInfo = array(
        'format' => $ffprobe->format($vid) // extracts file informations,
        'length' => $ffprobe->->get('duration'); // returns the duration property,
    );
    return $vidInfo;
}
```

You can find it's documentation here : https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/blob/master/README.md

You also can find several solutions like https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/getID3

But keep in mind it'll probably be mandatory to install something on your server, (be it with composer or by importing some code in your block plugin files)